# iconv not working on WAMP

Tags: php, iconv

I recently moved my php application to a local development machine using WAMP. I am now encountering an error that was not there when using CentOS.

My objective is converting all Latin characters into their "normal" counterpart.
This is what I was using

```
$haystack = "Que tu día y año se llenen de elegancia  ¡Feliz Navidad!";
$haystack = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', $haystack);
```

The desired output should be (as it was on my previous server):

> Que tu dia y ano se llenen de elegancia ? ?Feliz Navidad!

However on my WAMP environment I am getting the following error

> iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Any ideas? I am also open to any iconv alternatives.

Comment: Is the file definitely still encoded in UTF-8? Is there a chance it was changed by the transfer process?

Comment: Yes, the database was transferred entirely. What I can see is that my WAMP config uses libiconv where my CentOS want uses glibc. I don't know if this has anything to do with it.